# Ajax: How to grab a form with jQuery, and use Zend Form to validate it

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

In this situation, I have a simple form, not generated by Zend:

```
<form id='com-prefs'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='accept-sms' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='accept-phone' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='accept-email' />
  <!-- etc -->
</form>
```

The form is longer than this, but it's essentially just more inputs. Zend_Form's form creation seems bloated, and since I'll be working on this project with others, I don't feel like complicating things with Zend form creation. However, Zend_Form's validation seems much more useful, and I'd like to use it through Ajax.

My question is, how do I grab the above form with jQuery (or just regular JS), and convert it into something that I can make into a Zend_Form easily to use the below:

```
$form->isValid();
```

Is serializeArray() the route I want to go?

EDIT: Using ZF1

Comment: Btw are you using Zend 1 or 2. In ZF2 the forms are much better & validation is in the Entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was indeed serializeArray(). The Zend_Form validator takes in an array of 'name'=> 'value'=> = etc.

.serializeArray() creates a multidimensional array representing all elements in a form whose values are set (or in the case of checkboxes and radio buttons, has the value 'checked').

Answer (score 0):

I made something maybe it is useful for you.
In the **IndexController.php** I add this action:

```
public function checkformAction(){
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $form = new $data["zend_form"]();
        unset($data["zend_form"]);
        echo $form->processAjax($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    }else{
        echo false;
    }
}
```

In the global Javascript file I add this function:

```
function validate(form,zend_form){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/index/checkform/',
    data:  $(form).serialize()+'&zend_form='+zend_form,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {
        response = $.parseJSON(response);
        if(response == true){
            $(form).removeAttr("onsubmit");
            $("#submit").click();
        }
        $("ul.errors").remove();
        $.each(response,function(key,value){
            var errorlist = '<ul class="errors">';
            $.each(value,function(key,value){
                errorlist += '<li>'+value+'</li>';
            });
            errorlist += '</ul>';
            $("#"+key).after(errorlist);
        });
    }
  });   
  return false;
}
```

And Last in each form class in the the init() function I add the **onsubmit** attribute:

```
class Frontend_Form_Doc extends Zend_Form
{
   public function init()
   {
      $this->setMethod('post');
      $this->setAttrib("onsubmit","return validate(this,'Frontend_Form_Doc')");

      .....

   }
}
```